# How to read the frame buffer of webkit in android?

Tags: android, webkit, framebuffer

First of all I want to know if a web page has a graphics frame buffer?? and if yes how can I access that frame-buffer programatically...??..I am trying to read the frame buffer of the web-kit(webpage) in android. My research so far has shown that the web view control uses the web kit. However I am not able to figure out how can I read the current frame buffer of the web-kit(webpage).Later I want to overlay the contents of the frame buffer on video  I have visited a few SO links nothing has helped till now.

Any ideas that can give a push in the right direction will be really appreciated.